# I keep getting compiler error C2086

Tags: c++

So I got this the C++ Primer Plus and in one of the excersices I needed to writte a programm to get the BMI of a person i needed to ask for the height in feet and inches and then make a convertion to just inches, then ask the person their weight in pounds and convert it to kilograms ans that was it

I appreciate the help in advance =)

Keep getting this error 
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2086   'double inches': redefinition   ConsoleApplication14

```
  #include "stdafx.h"
  #include <iostream>

  using namespace std;

  int main()
{

    const double inchesFactor = 12;

    const double metersFactor = 0.0254;

    const double massFactor = 2.2;

    double height;
    double weight;
    double BMI;
    double inches;
    double mass;
    double meters;


    cout << "Enter height " << flush;
    cin >> height;
    cout << "Enter weight " << flush;
    cin >> weight;

    double inches = (height * inchesFactor);
    double mass = weight / massFactor;
    double meters = inches / 0.5;
    double BMI = mass / meters;

    cout << "Your BMI is " << BMI << endl;
```

Comment: So what is your question? What compiler error are you getting?  Which line is causing it?

Comment: You do not have to re-specify the type of a variable every time you assign to it. You only declare the type when you first declare the variable.

Comment: You could post the full error message. Then we could see what the problem is, where it is etc. Good plan?

Comment: there it is I am sorry for not posting the full error

Comment: Copy error messages from the Output window instead of the Error List.

Comment: Include (or summarize) a meaningful English error message in your title. Don't expect anyone to know what "C2086" means.

Comment: I believe if you read the full error (in the Output window, and not the "Error List"), the error message will be on two lines, and the second line will actually say, `"Previous definition was on line XXX"`, pointing you to the conflicting line.

Answer (score 0):

The code below runs, you need to delete the extra doubles. I removed the  `#include "stdafx.h"` beacuse i am not using VS, but you can put it back

```
#include <iostream>

  using namespace std;

  int main()
{

    const double inchesFactor = 12;

    const double metersFactor = 0.0254;

    const double massFactor = 2.2;

    double height;
    double weight;
    double BMI;
    double inches;
    double mass;
    double meters;


    cout << "Enter height " << flush;
    cin >> height;
    cout << "Enter weight " << flush;
    cin >> weight;

    inches = (height * inchesFactor);
    mass = weight / massFactor;
    meters = inches / 0.5;
    BMI = mass / meters;

    cout << "Your BMI is " << BMI << endl;

    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at your code. Here you declare a bunch of variables of type `double`:

```
double height;
double weight;
double BMI;
double inches;
double mass;
double meters;
```

Then you ask the user to input height and weight:

```
cout << "Enter height " << flush;
cin >> height;
cout << "Enter weight " << flush;
cin >> weight;
```

And here you make bunch of calculations:

```
double inches = (height * inchesFactor);
double mass = weight / massFactor;
double meters = inches / 0.5;
double BMI = mass / meters;
```

When you write `double inches = (height * inchesFactor);` you're telling the compiler that "I want a ***new*** variable of type `double` with the name `inches`, and I want to set it to the value of `(height * inchesFactor)`. But you can't make a new variable named `inches` because you have already declared a variable with that name earlier.

If you omit the type and just write `inches = (height * inchesFactor);` you are instead telling the compiler: "I want to set the variable `inches`, ***which I've declared elsewhere***, to the value of `(height * inchesFactor)`.

So to fix your code, replace the last block of code above to just:

```
inches = (height * inchesFactor);
mass = weight / massFactor;
meters = inches / 0.5;
BMI = mass / meters;
```

since you've already declared `inches`, `mass`, `meters` and `BMI` earlier.